# Mysterious HTTP 404 header in my own scripts

Tags: php, headers, nginx, custom-header

I have a WordPress 3.5.1 + nginx configuration. Its nginx configuration is this:

```
server {
    root /mysite/public_html;
    server_name wp.mysite;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        if ($uri !~ "^/uploads/") {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /mysite/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Note that WordPress's `index.php` is in `/mysite/public_html/`.

I'm also using [nginx helper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/). Since I'm only running a single site, I only used its permalink beautify function.

I noticed that my custom scripts (outside of WordPress) are returning 404 headers. For instance, if I put `index.php` into `/mysite/public_html/my/`, and point browser to `http://wp.mysite/my/`, the script will execute okay, even with correct MIME type, but with an HTTP 404 header.

Putting `header("Status: 200 OK");` (for fastcgi) won't work. In fact, it seems to ignore other headers such as `Cache-Control` and `Expires` as well. It did pick up `Content-type` header as I mentioned earlier. In fact, its header part is:

```
$sapi_type = php_sapi_name();
if (substr($sapi_type, 0, 3) == 'cgi')
    header("Status: 200 OK");
else
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($this->im, null, 80);
```

I can see the JPEG alright. But no other headers are sent. I'm wondering where do I start to debug this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's the `require('../wp-blog-header.php');` part who caused the HTTP 404 error. I replaced the header code with:

```
status_header(200);
nocache_headers();
```

Both are part of WordPress API. And the problem went away. I found this solution from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/integrating-wp-in-external-php-pages?replies=22

Comment: This post saved me.. Had been banging my head from last one day to understand the reason behind 404 error.